# How to get simple product id from configurable options in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, simple-product

I'm looking for a way to get the product Id of simple product using configurable options. I've following configuration options:

1. Material (as a select box)
2. Swatch color (As swatch)
3. Ring size (as a select box)

Is there any function in Magento2 through which I can achieve this?